# Will using aarch64-none instead of aarch64-elf yield any benefit in Bare Metal?

Tags: cross-compiling, raspberry-pi3, arm64, bare-metal

I am following along an [Rpi 3 bare metal](https://github.com/RazazRobotics/raspi3-tutorial/blob/master/02_multicorec/Makefile) tutorial.  I've spent a good amount of time on bare metal with the Rpi A+ and Zero using Dave Welche's excellent repo and other source as well.

The great thing about this Rpi 3 tutorial is

```
1) it's 64 bit
2) it's multi core
```

With my surface level understanding, I know that `aarch64-elf` will build a "binary" that's loadable by an OS that uses the ELF file format, such as any Unix based (Linux, OSX).

Whereas the `aarch64-none` is meant for bare metal, meaning it won't create any OS loader info into the resulting binary.

What's confusing is that [Rpi 3 tutorial](https://github.com/RazazRobotics/raspi3-tutorial/blob/master/02_multicorec/Makefile) build their tool chain as `aarch64-elf`.

If you look at [line 40](https://github.com/RazazRobotics/raspi3-tutorial/blob/master/02_multicorec/Makefile#L40) of the make file, he still ends up doing an `objcopy` which I *think* will strip away any ELF related info anyhow, correct?

So my question: is it worth it to go through and change their Makefiles to `aarch64-none` in every single example? They also didn't do a good job of making that a param unfortunately!

Is there any added benefit when in bare metal to `aarch64-none`? I am still going to have to do the `objcopy` anyways, correct?

Comment: There should really be no difference in output produced by the two for the same input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am answering your questions in a different order because some answers have direct implications for others.
*1) I am still going to have to do the objcopy?*
Yes.
*2) Is there any added benefit when in bare metal to aarch64-none?*
None I would be aware of.  ARM Trusted Firmware and u-boot are compiling fine with aarch64-elf for example.
*3) Is it worth it to go through and change their Makefiles to aarch64-none in every single example?*
I would say it is not. I would rather suggest to download and install the Linaro aarch64-elf toolchain from [here](https://releases.linaro.org/components/toolchain/binaries/latest/aarch64-elf/):
Download [gcc-linaro-7.2.1-2017.11-i686_aarch64-elf.tar.xz](https://releases.linaro.org/components/toolchain/binaries/latest/aarch64-elf/gcc-linaro-7.2.1-2017.11-i686_aarch64-elf.tar.xz) if your compiling system is running a 32 bits version of Linux, and [gcc-linaro-7.2.1-2017.11-x86_64_aarch64-elf.tar.xz](https://releases.linaro.org/components/toolchain/binaries/latest/aarch64-elf/gcc-linaro-7.2.1-2017.11-x86_64_aarch64-elf.tar.xz) if it is running a 64 bits one.

Installation procedure (x86_64 Linux):

```
mkdir -p /opt/linaro
wget https://releases.linaro.org/components/toolchain/binaries/latest/aarch64-elf/gcc-linaro-7.2.1-2017.11-x86_64_aarch64-elf.tar.xz
tar Jxf gcc-linaro-7.2.1-2017.11-x86_64_aarch64-elf.tar.xz -C /opt/linaro
export PATH=/opt/linaro/gcc-linaro-7.2.1-2017.11-x86_64_aarch64-elf/bin:$PATH

aarch64-elf-gcc  --version
aarch64-elf-gcc (Linaro GCC 7.2-2017.11) 7.2.1 20171011
Copyright (C) 2017 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```